# Why "Required kernel recording resources are in use by another document" error is thrown when I try to run Executable in Instruments->Allocations?

Tags: c++, xcode, allocation, instruments

But it works fine with `Instruments->Time Profiler`.

All the other documents are closed.

Am trying to find a tool to find how much memory is used by my c++ code.

Answer (score 15):

You can fix this without disabling SIP by running the following command in `zsh`. It will sign your binary with the `get-task-allow` entitlement, which allows debugging.

```
codesign -s - -v -f --entitlements =(echo -n '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "https://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"\>
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.security.get-task-allow</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>') <your executable>
```

Source: https://cocoaphony.micro.blog/2022/10/29/solving-required-kernel.html

Thanks to [Mārtiņš Možeiko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/675078/m%c4%81rti%c5%86%c5%a1-mo%c5%beeiko) for pointing me toward this solution.

Comment: When I run this script, I get "syntax error near unexpected token `('" It doesn't like the paren here: =(echo

Comment: It works for me if I save the xml as a file on disk, and then do `codesign -s - -v -f --entitlements=entitle.xml /path/to/my/app`

Comment: After the signing, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable SIP to be able to profile memory https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/disabling_and_enabling_system_integrity_protection?language=objc